# rowCount based on row value

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to do this..

```
    $userID = $_SESSION['user_session'];
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM orrs");
    $stmt->bindparam(":id", $userID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();


 echo   
"<div class='table-responsive'>
 <table class='table' border='1'>
     <tr class='head'>
     <h3>Snapshot</h3>
     <th>Se</th>
     <th>#s</th>
     <th>Ae</th>
     <th>Prt</th>
     <th>Pin</th>


     </tr>";


      while($userRows=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {


      if($userRows['stage'] == '1')
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . "Newn" . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $count . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $userRows['aow'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $userRows['pit'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $userRows['pgin'] . "</td>";


      }
      else if($userRows['stage'] == '2')
      {

      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . "Pendinn" . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $count . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $userRows['gfh'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $userRows['pt'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $userRows[trin'] . "</td>";
      }



  }
```

Basically, If the value in the row STAGE = 1 I want it to count those rows and give me the number.. If the value of STAGE = 2 I want it to count those rows and give me the number.

Right now, It is just counting all of the rows.. So for both of the IF statment its count number is saying 2, When there is only 1 in each section..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to execute three different statements, one to get all the rows (for you to loop over and create your output) and one to get each of the counts

```
//The current one
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM orrs");

//The get the count for stage '1'
$stage_1_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM orrs where STAGE = 1");
$stage_1_count = $stage_1_stmt->rowCount();

//The get the count for stage '2'
$stage_2_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM orrs where STAGE = 2");
$stage_2_count = $stage_2_stmt->rowCount();
```

You can execute these others to get the counts which you should use in place of $count in your loop.

Your while loop then becomes

```
while($userRows=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {


  if($userRows['stage'] == '1')
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . "Newn" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $stage_1_count . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $userRows['aow'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $userRows['pit'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $userRows['pgin'] . "</td>";


  }
  else if($userRows['stage'] == '2')
  {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . "Pendinn" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $stage_2_count . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $userRows['gfh'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $userRows['pt'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $userRows[trin'] . "</td>";
  }
}
```

Comment: as you see though, Im doing while loops. I cant do 3 different while loops or it wont work right.

Comment: You can use the same while loop, I'll update my answer

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you for the help!